# Is there a two-qudit Choi entanglement witness $W^{(+)}$?

Tags: entanglement, density-matrix, entanglement-witness

Example 2 in [arXiv:1811.09896](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.09896) states that the "Choi EW (entanglement witness) $W^{(+)}$ obtained from the Choi map in $d=3$ $\ldots$ is given by
\begin{equation}
W^{(+)} = \frac{1}{6} \left( \sum_{i=0}^{2} [ 2| ii \rangle \langle ii |  + | i,i-1 \rangle \langle i, i-1 | ] - 3 \mathrm{P}_{+}  \right) \nonumber,
\end{equation}
where $\mathrm{P}_+ = |\phi^+\rangle \langle \phi^+|$ with the Bell state $|\phi^+\rangle = (|00\rangle + |11\rangle + |22\rangle) / \sqrt{3}$." It is noted that this is applicable in the two-qutrit ($9 \times 9$ density matrix) setting.

I would like to know - if it exists - a two-qudit analogue, applicable to $16 \times 16$ density matrices. If it does, I presume the summation would run from 0 to 3, and the $\sqrt{3}$ in the new (obvious) Bell state formula be replaced by 2. Might the coefficient 2 be replaced by 3, and the $3 P_+$ by $4 P_+$? The $\frac{1}{6}$ does not seem of particular importance for testing purposes.

However, the last paragraph of [arXiv:1105.4821](https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.4821) strongly suggests that there is no simple/direct two-qudit analogue.